# $_SESSION value to being sent across

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm in a real pickel:

I'm making a login script and for some reason the $_SESSION variable is not sending across the page from my login check.

I have tested this with an pre PHP Ver 5.2.12 and it worked. Have previously used this method. But the site I'm using this method for now is PHP Ver 5.2.12

SO there are 2 differences between the two versions I have been able to notice, they are:

In the old version,

session.bug_compat_42   On  On  AND in the new = session.bug_compat_42  Off Off

Also

OLD VERersion

session.use_trans_sid   0   0 AND NEW session.use_trans_sid 1   1

Also the path for session.save_path are different in each version(does this matter??)
This is my code for the logged in page:

LOGGEDIN PAGE

```
<?php 
session_start();
$var_user = $_SESSION['US'];
//echo $var_user;//ouputs nothing =0
//if not logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['US'])) {
header ('Location:index.php');
 die();
}else if(isset($_SESSION['US'])){   
include('connect.php');
//rest of script goes here
}
```

and my code for the page that check the login details which is inside an if statement

PAGE THAT CHECKS THE VARABILES FROM THE LOGIN PAGE
TOP OF PAGE

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $var_pass =$_REQUEST['PW'] ; 
 $var_user =$_REQUEST['US'] ;
```

LATER IN THE PAGE

```
$_SESSION["US"]= $var_user;
//echo "login success";
header ('Location:loggedin.php');
```

This is absolutely doing my head in is possibly just a small error I'm not realising, any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added session_start in your login page?

Comment: no I haven't, should I??

Comment: do one thing. above each code, write the name of the file from where it is coming. I see there are 2 pages here. but Its getting difficult which code belongs to which page. or better, give the full code here. It would be easier to debug.

Comment: thanks have adjusted it, hopefully it appears more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
session_start();
```

at the top of login page.

Comment: I have session_start() at the top of the login page, the login check page and the logged in page, still does not work